# JavaEE Project doesn't read PrimeFaces is library jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, package

I am trying to open an old JEE project after adding primefaces JAR File into project is library, it seems that the project doesn't read jar files. I just take a screen shot for this problem to make you sure that the Class that i want to import already exist . [image: picture for more detail]

Comment: Is it on the build path?

Comment: Mind updating your post with the project's structure?

Comment: Mind using the correct tags?

Comment: What kind of Projekt is it? Maven, Ant or native Netbeans Project.... ? How did you added the jar? Have you executed build?

Comment: sorry for late it's a native one  and i added the jar file from project's properties.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a newer PrimeFaces version for a project that use an older one. Try to check which version of PrimeFaces was used for the project